# Exposing a container in Colima to a Docker container on host

Tags: docker, networking, apple-m1, host, colima

Hi I am currently have a Docker container on my m1 MacBook and am trying to connect to a database that is running on a container in Colima's VM. I am a bit new to networking and am not sure how to make the container's connect to one another. I want it so that when I use the ip addresses from the command for both containers:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <CONTAINER_ID>
```

and when I ping these ip addresses from both containers, they should be able to receive the signals.

Comment: "I am currently have a Docker container on my m1 MacBook" MacOS cannot run containers directly. They must be inside a VM. Is this container running inside the Colima VM, or another VM?

Answer (score 0):

Try running colima with `--network-address=true`. This will assign an external IP to the VM and make it reachable.

Look for more details [in the FAQ](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#the-virtual-machines-ip-is-not-reachable).